# why am I getting FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ClosedXML The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#

My code works fine locally, but when I go to run it on my server I get the error:

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ClosedXML, Version=0.97.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fd1eb21b62ae805b'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The ClosedXML.dll file is there on the server. But I am getting this error.

I've tried changing the version (each time copying over the matching dll) but it hasn't helped.

Is there anything else I can check to explain why the file can not be found?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can have such issue when you try to load x64 assembly under x86 environment or vice-versa